# Fixed point combinator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators, fixed-point-iteration

The fixed point combinator doesn't always produce the right answer given the definition:

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

The following code does not terminate:

```
fix (\x->x*x) 0
```

Of course, `fix` can't always produce the right answer, but I was wondering, can this be improved?

Certainly for the above example, one can implement some fix that looks like

```
fix f x | f x == f (f x)  = f x
        | otherwise       = fix f (f x)
```

and gives the correct output.

What is the reason the above definition (or something even better, as this one only handle function with 1 parameter) is not used instead?

Comment: The fix point combinator always returns a correct result, but it might not be the result you want, since it frequently involves bottom.

Comment: If you are interested in the deeper meaning of `fix`, this is an illuminating read: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fixed point combinator finds the least-defined fixed point of a function, which is ⊥ in your case (non-termination indeed is undefined value).

You can check, that in your case

```
(\x -> x * x) ⊥ = ⊥
```

i.e. `⊥` really is fixed point of `\x -> x * x`.

As for why is `fix` defined that way: the main point of `fix` is to allow you use [anonymous recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) and for that you do not need more sophisticated definition.

Comment: It is important to note that Haskell's [cpo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order#Continuous_functions_and_fixpoints) over which that definition of `fix` makes sense is not the usual ordering relation on the (say) real numbers.  Rather, it is the information-theoretic partial order where ⊥ is the undefined value that is a member of every (non-strict) data type in Haskell, and all the usual real numbers x are ⊥ ⊑ x.  A so-called _lifted_ _discrete_ CPO.

Comment: I think he meant domain-theoretic, not information-theoretic.

Answer (score 8):

Your example does not even typecheck:

```
Prelude> fix (\x->x*x) 0

<interactive>:1:11:
    No instance for (Num (a0 -> t0))
      arising from a use of `*'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (a0 -> t0))
    In the expression: x * x
    In the first argument of `fix', namely `(\ x -> x * x)'
    In the expression: fix (\ x -> x * x) 0
```

And that gives the clue as to why it doesn't work as you expect. The `x` in your anonymous function is supposed to be a function, not a number. The reason for this is, as Vitus suggests, that a fixpoint combinator is a way to write recursion without actually writing recursion.  The general idea is that a recursive definition like

```
f x = if x == 0 then 1 else x * f (x-1)
```

can be written as

```
f    = fix (\f' x -> if x == 0  then 1 else x * f' (x-1))
```

Your example

```
fix (\x->x*x) 0
```

thus corresponds to the expression

```
let x = x*x in x 0
```

which makes no sense.

Comment: he probably wanted `fix (\x->x*x)` (without the 0), which does typecheck

Comment: I doubt it. He seemed to expect it to produce output under his revised `fix`, which your version doesn't do (there being no `Show` instance for functions). My admittedly speculative take was that he expected x*x to become 0*0 in that situation, short-circuiting the process somehow.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely qualified to talk about what the "fixpoint combinator" is, or what the "least fixed point" is, but it is possible to use a `fix`-esque technique to *approximate* certain functions.

Translating [Scala by Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) section 4.4 to Haskell:

```
sqrt' :: Double -> Double
sqrt' x = sqrtIter 1.0
  where sqrtIter guess | isGoodEnough guess = guess
                       | otherwise          = sqrtIter (improve guess)
        improve guess = (guess + x / guess) / 2
        isGoodEnough guess = abs (guess * guess - x) < 0.001
```

This function works by repeatedly "improving" a guess until we determine that it is "good enough". This pattern can be abstracted:

```
myFix :: (a -> a)       -- "improve" the guess
      -> (a -> Bool)    -- determine if a guess is "good enough"
      -> a              -- starting guess
      -> a
fixApprox improve isGoodEnough startGuess = iter startGuess
  where iter guess | isGoodEnough guess = guess
                   | otherwise          = iter (improve guess)

sqrt'' :: Double -> Double
sqrt'' x = myFix improve isGoodEnough 1.0
  where improve guess = (guess + x / guess) / 2
        isGoodEnough guess = abs (guess * guess - x) < 0.001
```

See also Scala by Example section 5.3. `fixApprox` can be used to approximate the fixed point of the `improve` function passed into it. It repeatedly invokes `improve` on the input until the output  `isGoodEnough`.

In fact, you can use `myFix` not only for approximations, but for exact answers as well.

```
primeAfter :: Int -> Int
primeAfter n = myFix improve isPrime (succ n)
  where improve = succ
        isPrime x = null [z | z <- [2..pred x], x `rem` z == 0]
```

This is a pretty dumb way to generate primes, but it illustrates the point. Hm...now I wonder...does something like `myFix` already exist? Stop...Hoogle time!

[Hoogling `(a -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> a`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+a), the very first hit is `until`.

> `until p f` yields the result of applying `f` until `p` holds.

Well there you have it. As it turns out, `myFix = flip until`.

Comment: (Note that `primeAfter` isn't actually a correct example of finding a "fixed point")

Comment: +1 because, although you don't mention what `fix` actually does, I think this is the only answer to provide a function that resembles what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `iterate`:

```
*Main> take 8 $ iterate (^2) (0.0 ::Float)
[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
*Main> take 8 $ iterate (^2) (0.001 ::Float)
[1.0e-3,1.0000001e-6,1.0000002e-12,1.0000004e-24,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

*Main> take 8 $ iterate (^2) (0.999 ::Float)
[0.999,0.99800104,0.9960061,0.9920281,0.9841198,0.96849173,0.93797624,0.8797994]
*Main> take 8 $ iterate (^2) (1.0 ::Float)
[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
*Main> take 8 $ iterate (^2) (1.001 ::Float)
[1.001,1.002001,1.0040061,1.0080284,1.0161213,1.0325024,1.0660613,1.1364866]
```

Here you have all the execution history explicitly available for your analysis. You can *attempt* to detect the fixed point with

```
fixed f from = snd . head 
                   . until ((< 1e-16).abs.uncurry (-).head) tail 
               $ _S zip tail history
  where history = iterate f from
        _S f g x = f x (g x)
```

and then

```
*Main> fixed (^2) (0.999 :: Float)
0.0
```

but trying `fixed (^2) (1.001 :: Float)` will loop indefinitely, so you'd need to develop separate testing for convergence, and even then detection of repellent fixed points like 1.0 will need more elaborate investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define `fix` the way you've mentioned since `f x` may not even be comparable.  For  instance, consider the example below:

```
myFix f x | f x == f (f x)  = f x
          | otherwise       = myFix f (f x)

addG f a b =
  if a == 0 then
    b
  else
    f (a - 1) (b + 1)

add = fix addG -- Works as expected.
-- addM = myFix addG (Compile error)
```