# Can fixed-point functions be used on polynomials?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, algebra

I was thinking of a way to represent algebraic numbers in Haskell as a stream of approximations. You could probably do this by some root finding algorithm. But that's no fun. So you could add `x` to the polynomial, reducing the problem to finding it's fixed points.

So if you have a function in Haskell like

```
f :: Double -> Double
f x = x ^ 2 + x
```

I don't conceptually understand why fix doesn't work, which is to say, I can easily verify for myself that it doesn't work, but isn't 0 the true least fixed point of f? Is there another simple (as in definition size) fixed point function that would work?

Comment: `fix` finds the least _defined_ fixed point which in many cases is ⊥ (non-termination, error, ...). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8099449/700253

Comment: This is a very good question, but I find it quite difficult to answer without going too abstract. I'm trying to formulate a good answer.

Comment: As vitus says, the ordering where fix finds the least fixed point is domain ordering, rather than the regular ordering on Double.

Comment: If you look at the tag wiki for [fixed-point], you'll see that it's not the tag you were looking for.

Comment: @Vitrus, thanks for the clarification. I was also wondering if there is a fixed point function that doesn't only find the least fixed point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the implementation of the fix function:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

It doesn't work for primitive types like `Double`.  It's intended for types that have a more complex structure to them.  For instance:

```
g :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
g i = Just $ case i of
    Nothing -> 3
    Just _ -> 4
```

This function will work with `fix` because it yields information about its result faster than it reads its input.  in other words, the `Just` portion is known without looking at `i` at all, which enables it to reach a fixed point.

When your function is `Double -> Double`, and examines its input, `fix` won't work because there's no way to partially evaluate a `Double`.