# Guessing the type of fixed-point combinator

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fixpoint-combinators

My question is related to "fixed point combinator". According to [this Wikipedia page section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Lazy_functional_implementation) a function `fix` such that

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

is of type (or at least can be of type)

```
(a -> a) -> a
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Have you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099349/fixed-point-combinator-in-haskell)

Comment: Thanks Guvante, I have seen it but from what I understood of it, it is not exactly what I asked... What I would like is an analytical answer or a point to a general method to solve that kind of problem...

Comment: `fix f` is not `f`. It's `f (fix f)`.

Comment: you are right sorry, a typo when I sent the question. I corrected...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start from the definition

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

Since it takes an argument, `fix` must have a type that looks like

```
fix :: x -> y
```

It applies its argument to something, so in fact

```
fix :: (p -> q) -> r
```

It actually applies its argument to `fix f`, so

```
fix :: (r -> q) -> r
```

The final result is actually the result of this application, so

```
fix :: (r -> r) -> r
```